# Solving $ 6 \cdot 9^x - 13 \cdot 6^x + 6 \cdot 4^x =0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ 6 \cdot 9^x - 13 \cdot 6^x + 6 \cdot 4^x  =0 $$

I've had trouble solving this exercise. What I did was try to divide both sides by $6^x$ in order to get

$$ 6 \cdot \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x - 13 + 6 \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x=0$$

But I have no clue how to proceed! Any help appreciated

Comment: Certainly $x=\pm 1$ is a solution. So can there be any other solution?

Comment: @DietrichBurde No. I'm more interested in how to get to $\pm 1$

Comment: Try factoring the expression.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is going to be that $9^x = (3^x)^2$ and $4^x= (2^x)^2$. So the expression is a quadratic in $3^x$ and $2^x,$ and you can factor it, like lulu says.

Answer (score 1):

Call $(\frac{3}{2})^x=u;  (\frac{2}{3})^x=\frac{1}{u}$ You get a quadratic equation for u , and in the end x by log